# classes.jar missing for debug app version with Gradle plugin 3.6.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

We are using jacoco to generate some coverage results for us and we have it like this:

```
val run: JavaExec by tasks
run.setArgsString(
    """
    report ../coverage-instrumentation.ec --xml ../coverage-instrumentation.xml
    --classfiles ../app/build/intermediates/app_classes/debug/bundleDebugClasses/classes.jar
    """.trimIndent().replace('\n', ' ')
)
```

The problem is that this bundleDebugClasses/classes.jar does not exist anymore after we updated to Gradle plugin 3.6.2. Any ideas where I can find the bundled classes.jar? Or can it be a problem due to something else failing and how can I figure it out? (trying for 2 days now).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think the current location with 3.6.2 is app/build/intermediates/app_classes/debug/classes.jar